# Binding Multiple Datagridview

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I am a newbie in C# so I don't know if I will address my problem correctly so please bear with me. I have 3 DataGridViews (`datagridview1`, `datagridview2`, `datagridview3`). All are located in the same window but they are in a different tab (I have a tab control).

The purpose of each `DataGridView` is to display data for three tables from database. So every time I click a button, it retrieves data. But here is my problem, when `datagridview1` displays the data after clicking the button, then I go to the next tab and click again the retrieve button, the `datagridview2` shows the data that was displayed to `datagridview1`. Same thing to `datagridview3`.

I'm using `DataTable` as the data source for those DataGridViews. And somewhere in my script the query will change so I think there's no problem with the query. What I found is that the `DataTable` does not clear it's data even when the query already changed.

I'm using WinForms, please help me. Thanks.

---

Here is the code I used in binding the datagridview to a datasource:

currentdatagrid.DataSource = execute.InitConn2(query, CompleteTablename);

### Note: "execute.InitConn2(query, CompleteTablename)" will return a datatable.

Comment: Can  you add some code?

Comment: Could it be that you are binding the same data table, to all three grids?

Comment: Ummm. yup I am using just one datatable. Is it advisable to use different datatable for each datagrid view??

Comment: If you are setting the data table to a new query result, you should reinitialise the data table first, and then fill it again. You have to clear it's data.

Comment: @zaphod, I edit my post, please see at the bottom part. Thanks!

Comment: No @Zaphod, you can use the same variable, but you must clear it's content when changing results, binding to a grid with a different state each time.

Comment: @StephenBorg - I do clear the datatable (datatable.Clear()) but still no effect. I try to use datatable.Reset() and somehow it worked (the datagridview1, 2 and 3 shows the column for their respective table) but the problem is it doesn't have data.

Comment: Try doing datatable = new DataTable(); ... Then fill the data table with data, and then bind the grid after that. Each time the data table has a different state, bind the grid there. You should see all the 3 data grids with different data - according to your queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try doing something like the following example and see if it works for you. The static method GetData returns a new data table each time. You need to update the SqlConnection with your own connection string.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataGrid dg1 = new DataGrid();
            DataGrid dg2 = new DataGrid();
            DataGrid dg3 = new DataGrid();

            dg1.DataSource = GetData("select * from table1");
            dg1.DataBind();

            dg2.DataSource = GetData("select * from table2");
            dg2.DataBind();

            dg3.DataSource = GetData("select * from table3");
            dg3.DataBind();
        }

        public static DataTable GetData(string sqlQuery) {
            try
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                // set your connection here
                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("");

                // execute query with your connection
                SqlDataAdapter adapt = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlQuery, conn);

                // open connection, fill data and close
                conn.Open();
                adapt.Fill(dt);
                conn.Close();

                return dt;
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

To use a dataset use the following:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataGrid dg1 = new DataGrid();
            DataGrid dg2 = new DataGrid();
            DataGrid dg3 = new DataGrid();

            DataSet ds = GetData(@"select * from table1;
                                        select * from table2;
                                        select * from table3");

            dg1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            dg1.DataBind();

            dg2.DataSource = ds.Tables[1];
            dg2.DataBind();

            dg3.DataSource = ds.Tables[2];
            dg3.DataBind();
        }

        public static DataSet GetData(string sqlQuery) {
            try
            {
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();

                // set your connection here
                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("");

                // execute query with your connection
                SqlDataAdapter adapt = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlQuery, conn);

                // open connection, fill data and close
                conn.Open();
                adapt.Fill(ds);
                conn.Close();

                return ds;
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks Stephen, I appreciate your time, the thing is I need to retain the data while I'm still on the same tab. And doing "DataTable dt = new DataTable();" will clear all the data everytime I click the retrieve button.

Comment: Is it possible to use 3 different datatable for each dg? Like dtable1 is for dg1 then dtable2 is for dg2 and so on. . . .

Comment: It is possible yes, but might not be the best practice. But in your case, you might be limited to use that approach.

Comment: One thing that keeps on bothering me is why does the query remain in the datatable even after I perform dtable.Clear(), can I array the datatable? (stupid question I guess).

Comment: Why not use a DataSet? You can bind the grids datagrid.DataSource = dataset.Tables[0]; Each data table would be specifically set for a particular grid?

Comment: I don't know how to use dataset, is it more flexible compare to datatable?

Comment: I updated my answer. If you want to edit your queries between different tabs, not sure if this solution suits you - but you can have 3 result sets with one call split between different tables.

Comment: Hi Stephen, the code works fine, no need to reset clear/reset the data capsule (like datatable). I really appreciate your help! Also thanks for the new knowledge, I know now how to use dataset.